# How to use COM without admin privileges?

Tags: r, com

I am on work machine without admin privileges, and I would like to both create [COM objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) and also use COM objects provided by other processes within R. Is there any way to do this?

I've looked at the following packages:

- [`statconnDCOM`](http://www.statconn.com/products.html) and related packages, but that *requires admin privileges*.
- [`RDCOMClient`](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) and [`RDCOMServer`](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMServer/), but they seem *no longer to be maintained* and dependencies either cannot be found or are incompatible with my R version (3.0.2)

Any other choices?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, if by "admin privileges" you mean access to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.  However, instead of installing the software administratively, you'll need to extract/copy it and register its CLSIDs, Interfaces, Typelibs and what not yourself in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

You may want to try [RegFromApp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html) around the installer and see what registry changes are made.  Note that this utility must run from the same directory as the installer to work correctly, and it only spies on the process it launches.  If the installer runs subprocess to register things, such as `regsvr32.exe`, you'll have to run the utility around such applications one at a time.

Perhaps the vendor can help you with this task, at least by telling you which registry changes they make explicitly and by telling which files contain type libraries that are registered during installation.